# How can I disable underline in Material-UI without removing the selection in Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, underline

I want to create `Autocomplete` with `TextField` component without underline. I have disabled underline using `InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}` in `TextField` props, it did its job, but it also removed the selection bar, so the question is, how can I accomplish this without removing the select bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable the dropdown list again, you need to spread all provided props in the nested property too (`InputProps`). So replace this line

```
<TextField {...params} InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }} />
```

With:

```
<TextField {...params} InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, disableUnderline: true }} />
```

Full working code:

```
<Autocomplete
  options={top100Films}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, disableUnderline: true }}
      label="Combo box"
    />
  )}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67142906/how-can-i-disable-underline-in-material-ui-without-removing-the-selection-in-aut]

Comment: Friendly note for those who stuggle to make this work (like I did): "inputProps" and "InputProps" are completely different properties, and both of them are sometimes needed for the same component.